# It isn't me who or that

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns, relative-pronouns

Which one is correct after 'me' 'him' 'you' etc.. That or who?

> 1. 1. It isn't me **that** took it.
>    2. It isn't  me **who** took it.
> 2. 1. It isn't me **that** 'X' hate , it's you.
>    2. It isn't me **who** 'X' hate , it's you.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

There's a good [Oxford Dictionary blog post](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/09/that-who-which/) that really delves into the differences between using *that*, *who* and *which*, but to answer your question, when referring to people neither is incorrect. As the post goes into, there are some people who argue that when referring to people only *who* should be used, but both are acceptable for most people.

However, in your sample sentences there is an issue with some of the tenses. As you're referring to events that occurred in the past, you should use **wasn't** instead of **isn't** in those sentences.

> It **wasn't** me that took it.
>
> It **wasn't** me who took it.

Comment: Hi      you're right i forgot about  wasn't  but the second example  is in the present ^_^ thank you

Comment: You're correct, it's only the first set that's incorrect. Modifying it accordingly. :)

Comment: @Cantalouping Many a teacher suggests using subjective pronoun after "be" verb.

Comment: @dz420 That's awfully pedantic.